# Scipy.misc.imresize() vs cv2.resize()

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, scipy

I've been following many tutorials on Neural Networks and Image Classification, many of them use those 2 commands to resize the input image in order to match it with the input size of the Neural Network.

What is the difference between the two? Are they equivalent? 
How do i decide which one is better?

Looking at the documentation of each command, they seem pretty much the same.

**Documentation**: [cv2.resize()](https://www.tutorialkart.com/opencv/python/opencv-python-resize-image/) , [scipy.misc.imresize()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.19.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html)

Comment: I think they are the same. Just people's choices.

Comment: It is just a matter of convenience for your coding and/or ease of use. If you are using primarily OpenCV, then use its one. If you are primarily using skimage, then use its one or the one from scipy (likely the same)

Comment: Potential differences are the number and kind of resampling methods. see https://chadrick-kwag.net/cv2-resize-interpolation-methods/ and https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html

Answer (score 0):

Going forward, avoid using `scipy.misc.<anything>` : it's deprecated and will be removed in a future scipy version.